# Is confusion matrix possible in one column

Tags: python, k-means, confusion-matrix

I am performing anomaly detection using K-Means. I am working with only one column, plotting those values and then within this column I am adding some anomalies.

[image]

**My question is**

if it is possible to perform confusion matrix for this ? If so what is the approach ?
Asking this since I have seen that confusion matrix needs y axis and x axis

Answer (score 1):

**Confusion matrix needs groun truth values and predicted values.**

You have _____, so you need other part for this multiclass confusion matrix.

Answer (score 1):

No, a confusion matrix doesn't make sense here. While you are assigning inputs to clusters, you do not know which cluster is 'correct' for each input. That is, it is not a supervised multi-class classification problem. You do not even know what each cluster "means".

All you can measure here are metrics like intra-cluster distance: how far on average are points from their assigned cluster? Lower is better. Metrics like silhouette score are probably even better: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silhouette_(clustering)